# Macro closure in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

How can this be done in Swift?

```
typedef void(^CompletionBlock)(BOOL finished);
```

Comment: I think it would be something like `typealias CompletionBlock = (Bool) -> Void` loading up xcode to check

Comment: Swift doesn't have macros like C does. (and in C/Objective-C typedef isn't a macro anyway.) You want type alias, as outlined in Dávid's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define a `typealias` like this:

```
typealias CompletionBlock = (_ finished: Bool)->Void
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's not compiling when I use it in another class? func optInNewPrivacyPolicy(completionBlock: @escaping CompletionBlock){...}

Comment: @Luda that function declaration with an empty function body `func optInNewPrivacyPolicy(completionBlock: @escaping CompletionBlock){}` compiles just fine for me. What errors do you receive? You most probably have issues inside your function body.

Comment: This function is another class. The error is: Use of undeclared type 'CompletionBlock'

Comment: @Luda then you have declared your `typealias` in the wrong scope. You most probably declared it inside a single class. If you need to use the `typealias` in your whole project, simply declare it in the global scope (in any `.swift` file in your project outside any type declaration's scope).

Comment: Amazing! This is what I was looking for!